# I am trying to clean up my data that I created but it is not stripping anything

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to strip `<br>` among other things but when I print it out or look in my text file, nothing happens. The code runs without any error but it will not strip `<br>`. I think it might be because I have the file on read ('r') but I am not sure.

```
import urllib

# set workspace(This is where all your processing will be done)
arcpy.env.workspace = 'C://Users/desktop/'
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True


new = open('alexandriaweather.txt', 'r')
data = new.read()
data2 = data.strip("<br>")
print data2
new.close()
```

Comment: What are you really trying to do? All what you have written will do is remove zero or more of the string `'<br>'` from either end of the string stored in `data`.

Comment: @Tshepang your edit does not preserve the meaning of the original question!

Comment: Are you trying to strip out the end-of-line indicators?  data.strip('\n') is your friend...  As TBE pointed out in his first comment, your strip("<br>") will remove only the LITERAL TEXT (if it exists) <br> at the end of a row....

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist looks to me like user did not check that her `<br>` does not actually appear. With them invisible, the sentences don't make as much sense.

Comment: @Tshepang I think you're _probably_ right, but if you're not you would be masking the real problem.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I don't know what you mean, but I've done a rollback.

Comment: Sorry for the late response guys. I tried using replace("<br>","\n") and it worked. I am not to sure on the definition of the strip function but I guess it is only usable for long string. If any knows more about the strip function, can they tell us a little more about it?

Comment: @Tshepang <br> actually does appear when you open it up on notepad or words.

Comment: @JoshMullins but it does not appear on this site unless you enclose in `<code>` tags. It instead gets rendered as a line break.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So `strip` will just rip out `<br>` if it is at the end of the string. If you want to get rid of all the `<br>` instances you can use `replace`:

```
data2 = data.replace("<br>","")
```